# Retrieving data from sqlite3 via ajax from php to js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, sqlite

in my JS i want to read data from sqlite3 dbase. Here is `ajax` code:

```
function getHeaterCfg(rDate){
        var data  =  {
                isDateRequested : 1,
                reqDate : rDate
        };

        var jData = JSON.stringify(data);
        alert(jData);
        $.ajax({
                url: 'getLatestCfgHeater.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {'querySettings': jData},
                success: function(data) {
                        console.log("success");
                        //parse data
                }
        });
}
```

and here is php code:

```
<?php

    function var_error_log( $object=null ){
                ob_start();                    // start buffer capture
                var_dump( $object );           // dump the values
                $contents = ob_get_contents(); // put the buffer into a variable
                ob_end_clean();                // end capture
                error_log( $contents );        // log contents of the result of                    var_dump( $object )
    }


            $db = new SQLite3('./../../yyyy/config.db');
            $jsonData = json_decode($_POST['querySettings']);

            var_error_log(json_decode($jsonData));
            $isDateRequested = $jsonData->isDateRequested;
            if ($isDateRequested == True) {
                    $date = $jsonData->reqDate;
                    $stmt = $db->prepare('Select * from cfgs where date like \'(?)%\'');
                    $stmt->bindValue(1, $date);
            }
            else {
                    $stmt = $db->prepare('Select * from cfgs');
            }

            $resSql = $stmt->execute();
            var_error_log($resSql);
            echo json_encode($resSql);
    ?>
```

and here is php error.log:

```
[Thu Jan 07 14:37:37 2016] [error] [client xxxx] PHP Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /var/www/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/getLatestCfgHeater.php on line 15, referer: http://xxxx/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/sel3.html
[Thu Jan 07 14:37:37 2016] [error] [client xxxx] NULL\n, referer: http://xxxx/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/sel3.html
[Thu Jan 07 14:37:37 2016] [error] [client xxxx] object(SQLite3Result)#4 (0) {\n}\n, referer: http://xxxx/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/sel3.html
[Thu Jan 07 14:37:37 2016] [error] [client xxxx] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: querySettings in /var/www/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/getLatestCfgHeater.php on line 13, referer: http://xxxx/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/sel3.html
[Thu Jan 07 14:37:37 2016] [error] [client xxxx] NULL\n, referer: http://xxxx/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/sel3.html
[Thu Jan 07 14:37:37 2016] [error] [client xxxx] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/getLatestCfgHeater.php on line 16, referer: http://xxxx/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/sel3.html
[Thu Jan 07 14:37:37 2016] [error] [client xxxx] object(SQLite3Result)#3 (0) {\n}\n, referer: http://xxxx/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/sel3.html
```

Shall i use GET method instead POST?
Why json_decode on php side is complaining?

chorme says that

```
 jData = "{"isDateRequested":1,"reqDate":"7-1-2016"}"
```

so i think its valid `json` format...

Can you please point me how can i get this data?
Reagrds J.